# Container fluid on one side only

Tags: uikit, getuikit

I have a 2 columns grid in a uk-container and what I actually want to achieve is for the second column to take up the rest of the horizontal space available. What would be the best pratice using uikit? Thanks.

Comment: maybe just use offset for the first column ..

Answer (score 0):

you should look into `uk-width-expand`

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little bit (maybe a small example of usage)? As it stands, this answer is little more than a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below - Perfect for you:

```
<div class="uk-container" uk-grid>
<div class="uk-width-1-3">Fixed Width</div>
<div class="uk-width-expand">the rest of the horizontal space available</div>
```

OR  You can use like below if you want to generate width according content:

```
<div class="uk-container" uk-grid>
<div class="uk-width-1-3">Fixed Width</div>
<div class="uk-width-auto">the rest of the horizontal space available</div>
```

Note : uk-width-auto only generates width as per content.